# Google Sign in redirect to google.com instead of the application after it allow

Tags: ios, swift, gmail, ios10, google-signin

Google Sign in redirect to google.com instead of the application after it allow. This is an issue for the iOS 10 but in other devices with latest iOS version works fine. Please give some solution for this.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Show some code how are you doing it, is it from documentation , if it is then check your URL schemes if Plist all set correctly or not.

Comment: I have added code as per the document provided and the URL schemes as well. It works for the device with the ios version of 11 but has problem on the device with ios version 10. Why this happens only for ios 10?

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this issue by adding and implementing delegates methods on the app delegates as,

```
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = "your_client_id"
GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
```

I have both facebook and google signin so I returned both method like this,

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let handled = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    let googleHandler = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: "com.apple.SafariViewService", annotation: nil)
    return handled || googleHandler
}
 // [END openurl]
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {
    let checkFB = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
    let checkGoogle = GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url as URL?,sourceApplication: sourceApplication,annotation: annotation)
    return checkGoogle || checkFB
}
```